# Bash script delete file inside another folder if present in both with extension *.c

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Write a shell script that deletes all C sources in one directory if they are in the structure of another directory. The first argument on the command line is the directory where the C sources are located, and the second is the directory where the search starts.

I need the full code if possible, because I have written this and it doesn't work for my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then 
        echo "for execution complete the line of command: $0 dir1 dir2"
        exit 1
else 
        if [ ! d ~/$2 ]
        then
        echo "write a directory in order to do the search"
        exit 1
        fi
fi
for fis in *.c
do
        cat $fis
        rm -i $fis
done
```

The above is what I've tried.

Comment: Well, what have you tried and where are you stuck? A simple approach is to run `find` with the 2nd parameter limiting the results to files to `"*.c"` and save it a temporary file. Then loop over the files in the 1st directory and `grep` against the files in your temporary file. If it matches one  of the filenames in your temporary file, then delete the file, otherwise keep it. (note: you will have to trim the path part of the filename from both to make sure you are comparing name against name)

Comment: Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the list of all files, present in that second directory. That list should be saved in a file. The search can be done like this:

```
find <second_directory> -type f -name *.c >list_of_files.txt
```

Then you write a loop which goes over the first directory, and checks with `list_of_files.txt`, if the file is present there (use `grep` for this), delete it.

As you're working with Linux (no recycle bin), I'd propose to write the filenames, which are to be deleted, to a temporary file, and if this is correct, only then add a `rm` in front of it.

Comment: How do I write the loop? I used grep and it says that I shouldn't search in a directory with it.